# How do I split a CSV file based on the column data?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm given a alphabet.CSV file with columns A B C D. In column B, the data entered is either 1, or 2.
I'm tasked to write a shellscript that reads data out of the CSV file and split it into two files with names B_1.csv and B_2.csv. Each of these files must only contain data rows belonging to the respective data in column B.
i.e:
B_1.csv should contain all the columns A B C D, but in column B, only 1 shows up.
B_2.csv should contain all the columns A B C D, but in column B, only 2 shows up.

Here is what I have so far:

```
file=alphabet.csv

 
if grep -c '1', file
   then cat >> B_1.csv
   else cat >> B_2.csv
fi
 
exit
```

However, this gives me the following error:

> command not found

I'm a bit lost. I'm looking through guides, quite understand what they mean, but I'm not sure how I could do this with "sed" or "awk" or other formats.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KN4if.jpg)

Comment: Could you please share an example of `alphabet.csv` ?

Comment: You shouldn't be getting 'command not found'.  Are you getting that while the script is running, or is it saying that the script is not found?  Try `./script` instead of `script`.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a bad place to _learn_ programming. It's a place for people that already know programming to solve programming problems. Start with a [good introduction into shell](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide). For your specific problem, you may read [how to read a file field by field in bash](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) and learn `awk`. `I'm given a alphabet.CSV file with columns A B C D` It would be way easier if you would _show_ a sample lines from the file, instead of explaining.

Comment: Hi, apologies for being unclear with my descripton, I have taken a photo and attached to my initial post for your reference,I hope it helps

Comment: Can you post a sample of the csv?

Comment: Pictures of text are a _really_ quick way to attract downvotes. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: The sample omits the fourth column; you say you have a D column too.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I'm not worthy to even be on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` is well suited to this task:

```
awk '$2 == 1{print > "B_1.csv"} $2 ==2 {print > "B_2.csv"}' FS=, alphabet.csv
```

This can be easily generalized to more possible values in column 2:

```
awk '{print > ("B_" $2 ".csv")}' FS=, alphabet.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

`cat` without a file name argument will write standard input to standard output. You probably don't have anything meaningful on standard input (unless you are manually typing in the file one line at a time).  Similarly, your `grep` command would count the number of occurrences of `1,` on all lines of the file (and basically always succeed; so not a very good command to put in a condition).

*Probably* you mean you want to write the current *line* to a different file, depending on what it contains.  Awk makes this really easy;

```
awk -F ',' 'BEGIN { IFS=OFS } { print >($2 == "1" ? "B_1.csv" : "B_2.csv") }' alphabet.csv
```

In brief, this splits the current line on commas, examines the second field, and writes to one file or the other depending on what it contains. (Awk in general reads one line at a time, and applies the current script to each line in turn.)  The compact but slightly obscure notation `a ? b : c` checks the truth value of `a`, and returns `b` if it is true, otherwise `c` (this "tertiary operator" exists in many languages, including C).

The assignment `OFS=FS` makes sure the output it comma-separated, too (the default is to read and print whitespace-separated fields).

If you wanted to do this in pure shell script, it would look something like

```
while IFS=, read -r one two three four; do
    case $two in
      1) echo "$one,$two,$three,$four" >>B_1.csv;;
      2) echo "$one,$two,$three,$four" >>B_2.csv;;
    esac
done <alphabet.csv
```

But really, use Awk. An important task when learning shell scripting is also to learn when the shell is not the most adequate tool for the job; you generally tend to learn `sed` and Awk (or these days a modern scripting language like Python) as you go.

Both of these are slightly brittle with real-world CSV files, where a comma may not always be a column delimiter. (Commonly you have double-quoted fields which may contain literal commas which are not acting as delimiters, but CSV is not properly standardized.)